# Apply style to elements in a div with a class

Tags: html, css, styles

What I am able to do:

HTML:

```html
<div id="test">
    HELLO! 
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#test {
   color:#F00;
}

#test input[type=text] {
   background-color:#000;
}
```

What I'd like to do is the same thing if the `#test` has not an `ID` but a class:

```
<div class="test">
   ...
```

How should I write the CSS in this case?

Comment: `#test, .test {}` and `#test input[type="text"], .test input[type="text"] {}` if you weirdly need to be able to handle both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.` to signify a class.

```
.test {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes... this is not the problem... My problem is about the input under the class

Comment: Add `input` after the `.test`, so `.test input`

Comment: Same concept... see DevlshOne's answer to have it spelled out for you. Also would recommend that you take some time to go through one of the many many CSS tutorials on the web. (I have to say that this is the first time I've seen someone using the attribute-selector and /not/ understand basic class-selectors first!)

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace the `#` with a `.` (period):

```
.test {
   color:#F00;
}

.test input[type=text] {
   background-color:#000;
}
```